# Batch duplicating last row

Tags: jdbc

So i'm creating a program, what i'm trying to do this time is to copy the content from a JTable plus other things and insert them into a PostgreSQL table, the thing is, it duplicates the data from the last row only by the ammount of rows existing, for example, if the last row says 'Cat' and there are 5 rows, it will insert into the PostgreSQL table 5 rows with the word 'Cat' ignoring the data of the others before the final row.

```
try{
                Connection conn = null;
                PreparedStatement pst = null;
                Calendar calendario = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
                String hora = Integer.toString(calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                int minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                int rows=table.getModel().getRowCount();
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ruleta",
                        "postgres", "123456");
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                 String date = sdf.format(new Date()); 
                String queryco = "Insert into tickets(no_ticket,animal,hora,fecha,apuestabsf,ruleta, pagado, premio) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(queryco);
                for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
                {

                    String jugada = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                    String ruleta = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                    String apuesta = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 2);

                    pst.setInt(1, variable.ticket);
                    pst.setString(2, variable.animal);
                    pst.setString(3, hora + ":" + minutos);
                    pst.setString(4, date);
                    pst.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText()));
                    if(chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec1);
                     if(chckbxNewCheckBox_1.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec2);
                     if(chckbxNewCheckBox_2.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec3);
                     if(chckbxNewCheckBox_3.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec4);
                     if(chckbxNewCheckBox_4.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec5);
                     if(chckbxNewCheckBox_5.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec6);
                     if(chckbxNewCheckBox_6.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec7);
                     if(chckbxNewCheckBox_7.isSelected() == true) pst.setString(6, selec8);
                    pst.setString(7, "No decidido");
                    pst.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText()) * 30);

                    pst.addBatch();

                }
                pst.executeBatch();

                conn.commit();
                }

                catch(Exception e){
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
```

Comment: you do not handle jugada, ruleta, qpuesta in your PreparedStatement?!

Comment: Jesus Christ, i don't know what happened yesterday, must have had a brain fart, sorry.

Comment: so we should consider your question resolved for now (you might want to delete it in that case?) or is there still something you need help with?

Comment: yes, can't i give u a positive point or something ?

Comment: you could by accepting / upvoting my answer- thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieve some data from the table:

```
 String jugada = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 0);
 String ruleta = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 1);
 String apuesta = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 2);
```

But fail to insert them anywhere into you database.